# "sh: 1: file: not found" thrown in Perl

Tags: perl, file-upload

So this is an issue I see thrown around on several coding help-sites that always have a slight variation. I'm not entirely familiar with what it means, and what's even more curious is that this error is thrown midway through a larger `Upload.pm` script, and does not cause any sort of fatal error. It gets tossed into my error log somewhere during this unless conditional snippet

```
     # If this is the first slice, validate the file extension and mime-type. Mime-type of following slices should be "application/octet-stream".
  unless ( defined $response{'error'} ) {
    if ( $slice->{'index'} == 1 ) {
      my ($filename, $directory, $extension) = fileparse($path.$parent_file, qr/\.[^.]*/);

      unless ( is_valid_filetype($slice->{'tmp_file'}, $extension) ) {
        $response{'error'} = "Invalid file type.";
        $response{'retry'} = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, let me be perfectly honest. I don't really understand the error message, and I could really use some help understanding it, as well as solving it.
Our Perl based web app has refused to let us upload files correctly since upgrading to Debian Bullseye, and I've been stuck debugging this code I didn't write for a few days now. I'm wondering if the upgrade depreciated some Perl modules, or if the directories to said modules are no longer working?

I'm testing this in a Ubuntu based Docker environment running Debian Bullseye on an Apache 2 server.

If you need any more context, clarification, etc, please let me know.

is_valid_filetype() looks like this:

```
sub is_valid_filetype
{
  my ($tmp_file, $extension) = @_;

  if ( $tmp_file && $extension ) {
    # Get temp file's actual mime-type.
    my $mime = qx/file --mime-type -b '${tmp_file}'/;
    $mime =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;

    # Get valid mime-types matching this extension.
    my $dbh = JobTracker::Common::dbh or die("DBH not available.");
    my $mime_types = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT `mime_types` FROM `valid_files` WHERE `extension` = ?', undef, substr($extension, 1));

    if ( $mime && $mime_types ) {
      if ( $mime_types !~ /,/ ) {
        # Single valid mime-type for this extension.
        if ( $mime eq $mime_types ) {
          return 1;
        }
      } else {
        # Multiple valid mime-types for this extension.
        my %valid_mimes = map { $_ => 1 } split(/,/, $mime_types);
        if ( defined $valid_mimes{$mime} ) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `is_valid_filetype` is doing anything with the shell? Is it defined in that module, and can you show it?

Comment: It seems clear that `is_valid_filetype()` returns false (and some error flag is set), so that particular function, whatever it is, finds that the "_filetype_" isn't "_valid_".   In order to be able to say anything about whys and hows we'd need to see the function (code) and the data (file names etc).  So yes, need more information.  Also, it isn't clear to me what you mean by error being "_thrown midway_" -- the shown code only assigns to what would be some data structure (`%response`).

Comment: Hope this additional context added helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's a message from `sh` (not Perl). It concerns an error on line `1` of the script, which was apparently an attempt to run the `file` utility. But `sh` couldn't find it.

The code in question executes this command using

```perl
qx/file --mime-type -b '${tmp_file}'/
```

Install `file` or adjust the PATH so it can be found.

---

Note that this code suffers from a code injection bug. It will fail if the string in `$tmp_path` contains a single quote (`'`), possibly resulting in the unintentional execution of code.

Fixed:

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote( "file", "--mime-type", "-b", $tmp_file" );
qx/$cmd/
```

Comment: Possibly a stupid follow-up question, but where would the file utility be located? is that supposed to be installed on Ubuntu somewhere? I'm wondering if my Docker environment is missing something.

Comment: /usr/bin/file Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Not sure if it's there by default or provided by a package.

Comment: One last question, just because you have been a fantastic help here. Do you have any resources on installing the file utility? I did a `find ~` in Ubuntu, and I can't seem to find it installed.

Comment: Wait, I ran `$ sudo apt-get install -y file` and it said file is already installed to the newest version. I may have to open a new question to makes sure my web app is pointing to the right directory for utilities. Hey, I appreciate the help! I can't complain about learning more, at the very least.

Comment: @OldsDiesel `which file` or `where file` will tell you where it is located, if it is installed in your current path.

Answer (score 1):

Debian Bullseye was reading our CSV files as the wrong mime-type. It was interpreting the file command as application/csv, despite obviously not being an application.

This may be an actual bug in Bullseye, because both my boss and I have scoured the internet with no lucky finding anyone else with this issue. I may even report to Bullseye's devs for further awareness.

The fix was manually adding in our own mime-types that interpreted this file correctly.

It took us dumping the `tmp` directory to confirm the files existed, and triple checking I had my modules installed.

This was such a weird and crazy upstream issue that either of us could not have imaged it would be the file type interpretation at an OS level in Bullseye.

I really hope this helps someone, saves them the time it took us to find this.